# Java EE, differentiate context by path

Tags: java, glassfish, path-finding

I'm working on a workaround for the problem, that glassfish does not support individual certificates for virtual hosts.

My Application is supposed to be running context dependent based on which customer wants access to his data. I actually wanted to use seprarate domains for that, but since that is not possible, i've come up with a different idea:

I want to differentiate customers by the path they are entering.
For example:
www.application.com/customer1/pages/page.jsf or www.application.com/customer2/pages/page.jsf

But i dont know how to implement that. As far as i know, these adresses indicate paths on the webserver. Can i somehow do this, with the application still finding the pages?

Preferebly i want to store these entries (customer1 and customer2) in an external file so i can add a new entry without having to touch the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean SSL certificates. I would consider setting up a reverse proxy that handles the multiple domains and their SSL encryption and forwards the requests to normal HTTP on Glassfish.

In the application itself the distinction by customers can be made via the login they use (roles/groups, ...). If simply using a path or domain to distinguish it's quite easy to access secured resources from different customers. If you want to have the domain information you can simply add a header in the proxy server to the incoming HTTP request.

As for candidates for such a proxy I can recommend [NGINX](http://nginx.org/) which is easy to set up. You can also use Apache or many others for doing so.

Comment: I thought about distingushing them by login, but that would mean, every username would have to be unique across all customers(In my application, there are dozens uf users for ever customer). I don't know if i want that, it could lead to confusion on the customers side. As for the Proxy idea: I've heard about that solution, but I have even less of an idea how to do that. But it seems I have no choice.

Comment: I took a quick peek at the documentation. Do I have to set up a proxy directive for every single page on the glassfish webserver?

Comment: You don't have to specify single pages, however you have to specify the different domains. Found this explanation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

As for distinguishing by login there are countless options that depend on your choices of security. If the login is an E-Mail Address, it is unique. You could retrieve the domain information from the HTTP header and look up users using that additional information, ...

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm actually making good progress. Except that I don't seem able to manipulate the header in nginx. I've added "add_header customer customer1;" before proxy_pass, but its not there when i deconstruct the header later.

Comment: Major problem: Because I'm using a proxy my Sessions aren't consistent on the glassfish server. But I rely greatly on that. My whole concept for the application relys on @SessionScoped beans.

Comment: Header : http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header
The proxy does not in any way impact your session cookies if you do not tell him to do so. BUT as you are now accessing your server from multiple domains and session cookies are domain specific, you will have a different session for each domain

Comment: But I can see that my Glassfish webserver sends a new sessionID every time I access the Webserver via proxy. When I access the webserver directly, it only generates the cookie once and the client sends it back every time it does a request. If I work via proxy, the client only sets the cookie of nginx. Even if the proxy would always use the same Session on the webserver I cant use that, I need to store user-specific data in the session on the webserver itself.

Comment: Glassfish seems to be aware that something is wrong with the session. He manipulates links, there looking like this: "...page2.jsf;jsessionid=408e1a9520f20024a37ccf41d256". Glassfish doesn't do that when I access it directly (not via proxy)

Comment: Better create a new question with your nginx config. Btw many example configurations are available if you google.